Admob rewarded ad is shown only once
I am building an app using React Native expo. I am trying to implement rewarded ad. I copied the code from documentation and it works. In my application, users can watch as many ads as they want in order to earn game coins. The issue is in my implementation, the rewarded ad can be seen only once and if the user tries to watch one more ad the user sees an error:

Error: RewardedAd.show() The requested RewardedAd has not loaded and
could not be shown.

This implementation is in a modal. So if I close the modal, open it and press button to watch the rewarded ad again it works. As this is not a good experience on user side, the ad should be seen even without closing the modal. I will be very glad if there is something to fix this issue.
Here is my implementation:
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  RewardedAd,
  RewardedAdEventType,
  TestIds,
} from "react-native-google-mobile-ads";

const adUnitId = __DEV__
  ? TestIds.REWARDED
  : "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxx/yyyyyyyyyyyyyy";

const rewarded = RewardedAd.createForAdRequest(adUnitId);

export const useRewardedAd = () => {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

  const watchAd = () => {
    if (loaded) {
      rewarded.show();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribeLoaded = rewarded.addAdEventListener(
      RewardedAdEventType.LOADED,
      () => {
        setLoaded(true);
      }
    );
    const unsubscribeEarned = rewarded.addAdEventListener(
      RewardedAdEventType.EARNED_REWARD,
      (reward) => {
        console.log("User earned reward of ", reward);
      }
    );

    // Start loading the rewarded ad straight away
    rewarded.load();

    // Unsubscribe from events on unmount
    return () => {
      unsubscribeLoaded();
      unsubscribeEarned();
    };
  }, []);

  // No advert ready to show yet
  if (!loaded) {
    return null;
  }

  return watchAd;
};

I use watchAd in this component:
import { View, Text, Alert } from "react-native";
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Entypo, FontAwesome, FontAwesome5 } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import EarnRow from "./EarnRow/EarnRow";
import { PlayerInformationContext } from "@/context/PlayerInformation";
import { useRewardedAd } from "@/hooks/useRewardedAd/useRewardedAd";

const Earn = () => {
  const watchAd = useRewardedAd();

  const {
    money,
    seenAdsCount,
    health,
    setHealth,
    setMoney,
    handleSeenAdsCount,
  } = useContext(PlayerInformationContext);
  const handleEarn = async (type: string) => {
    switch (type) {
      case "getMoney":
        if (seenAdsCount < 10) {
          handleSeenAdsCount(seenAdsCount + 1);
        }
        if (watchAd) {
          watchAd();
        }
        break;
      case "getHealth":
        if (money >= 100) {
          setHealth(health + 12);
          setMoney(money - 100);
          Alert.alert("Enerji Topladın!", "12 enerji puanı kazandın!");
        } else {
          Alert.alert("Yetersiz Altın!", "Bu işlem için yeterli altının yok.");
        }
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }
  };

  return (
    <View className="w-full h-full items-start justify-start">
      <Text className="w-full mt-10 text-center text-white font-bold text-4xl">
        Kazan
      </Text>

      <EarnRow
        icon={
          <FontAwesome5
            name="bitcoin"
            size={40}
            className="-rotate-12 bg-white rounded-full"
            color="orange"
          />
        }
        coinAmount="+30"
        rewardText="Ücretsiz"
        rewardAction={() => handleEarn("getMoney")}
        buttonIcon={<Entypo name="video" size={24} color="white" />}
      />

      <EarnRow
        icon={<FontAwesome name="heart" size={40} color="red" />}
        coinAmount="+12"
        rewardText="100"
        rewardAction={() => handleEarn("getHealth")}
        buttonIcon={
          <FontAwesome5
            name="bitcoin"
            size={24}
            className="-rotate-12 bg-white rounded-full"
            color="orange"
          />
        }
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Earn;


For those if you have the same issue as well, I found how to fix:
const unsubscribeClosed = rewarded.addAdEventListener(
      AdEventType.CLOSED,
      () => {
        rewarded.load();
        Alert.alert("Tebrikler!", "Reklamı izleyerek ödül kazandın.");
      }
    );

This is going to trigger when user closes the ad. It will load the new ad and when you press the button to watch a new ad, it is going to open without any problem. I found it on github account of the "react-native-google-mobile-ads". There are more evens on AdEventType and others. Here you can find all:
https://github.com/invertase/react-native-google-mobile-ads/blob/main/src/ads/RewardedAd.ts
And the documentation of "React Native Google Mobile Ads"
https://docs.page/invertase/react-native-google-mobile-ads/displaying-ads
